# Scatter plot chart with positive and negative axis plus label in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have 3 columns of data, one is the label, the second and third are numeric values with a range from positive to negative numbers.

I couldn't create a scatter plot with a label in each of these points, because I didn't find how to get the label value from this column, as X is column A value and Y is column B value.

[image]

```
DATA:
LABEL   X-AXIS    Y-AXIS
Apple    -5         3
Banana    0        -5
[and so on]
```

Comment: You sample data gives me [this chart](https://imgur.com/nwMnhLs). By default, you have the legend at the bottom. If that is not what you want, can you edit your question to show us an image showing the desired result

Comment: I don't see any points at (-5,3) or (0,-5). Please post consistent data.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: You're plotting (1,-5), (2,3), (1,0) and (2,-5). I believe that's not what the OP wants — but I agree that the question is unclear.

Comment: @Scott ah!, I see, I,m used to working with series not individual points

Comment: The data is just an example!! Banana or Apple should be the label, but as a label i get only the numbers from x or y!

Answer (score 1):

1. Select only the data and insert a scatter chart

[image]

2. Select, then right-click on one of the data points and select "Add Data Labels" from the dropdown menu

[image]

3. Right-click on the data point again and select "Format Data Label" from the dropdown menu

[image]

4. Check "Value From Cells" and choose the range for the labels

[image]

Your chart should now look like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't have these options in my excel 2010 :(

Comment: But that's what i need!!

Comment: I believe that the horizontal axis is usually called X, and the vertical axis is usually called Y.  So I believe that you need to “Switch Row/Column”.  (But, if the OP says you’ve got it right, who am I to disagree?)